# Serialization error while sending data table to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

> There was an error in serializing body of message Method1: 'There was an error generating the XML document.'

I am getting this error when I am trying to pass a data-table as a parameter to a WCF method, I have already used such type of methods (that is `DataTable` as parameter) in my WCF service, that works fine.

However in this case, I think the reason could be the size of the `DataTable`, not sure though.

Already tried increasing `maxReceivedMessageSize`, `maxBufferSize` and `maxStringContentLength` to 5242880 that is 5 MB (which I think is more than enough), but no luck.

Found many related articles, but no one pointing to this particular issue, hence posted.

Please guide.

**`Update:`**

My `DataTable` also contains contains some XML contents, can this be the issue, since this is serialized in XML format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, but then i realized that i forgot to name the data table, just check if you are also missing it...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
...
dt.TableName = "Table1";
```

now pass the table as parameter, hope it helps

Comment: that was the same issue with me, many thanks to you, and others for their efforts :)

Comment: Thank you Sir for this answer. After countless Google searches, I finally found this answer which actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `behavior` configuration in your `App.config` files (and reference it in your services and endpoints):

- On the server:

  ```
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  ```
- On the client:

  ```
  <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="MyClientBehavior">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  ```

---

If that doesn't work, try setting the max values for the binding:

```
<bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBindingConf" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 sendTimeout="00:30:00">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                          maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                          maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                          maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                          maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: @Bravo: Did you reference the `behavior`? (with `<service name="SomeService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">...</service>` and the same on `<endpoint>`s)

Comment: Yes Otiel, i already did that for server config., but didn't find anything to bind on client side. so left it that way... have i done anything wrong. and i also wanted to know can this be the real reason of the error, since my datatable can't be greater than 1 or 2 MB.

Comment: @Bravo: Paste both your app.config files on some pastebin if you would like me to give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

here's a good example of How to increase the message length of a custom WCF web service hosted in SharePoint:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyFactory : MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType,
            Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {            
            ServiceHost host = new MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHost(
                serviceType, baseAddresses);

            if (host != null)
            {
                host.Opening += new EventHandler(OnHost_Opening);
            }

            return host;
        }

        private void OnHost_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Assert(sender != null);
            ServiceHost host = sender as ServiceHost;
            Debug.Assert(host != null);

            // Configure the binding values
            if (host.Description != null && host.Description.Endpoints != null)
            {
                foreach (var endPoint in host.Description.Endpoints)
                {                    
                    if (endPoint != null && endPoint.Binding != null)
                    {
                        BasicHttpBinding basicBinding = endPoint.Binding
                            as BasicHttpBinding;

                        if (basicBinding != null)
                        {
                            ConfigureBasicHttpBinding(basicBinding);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ConfigureBasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpBinding basicBinding)
        {
            Debug.Assert(basicBinding != null);
            basicBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            basicBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            basicBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
            basicBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        }
    }
}
As you can see I’m setting maximum length of the incoming messages.

Now we need to modify our service svc file to use our custom Factory Configuration:
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
    Service="MyNamespace.MyService, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"  
    CodeBehind="MyService.svc.cs"
    Factory="MyNamespace.MyFactory, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"%>
```

[example](http://www.sharepointguerrilla.com/post/How-to-increase-the-message-length-of-a-custom-WCF-web-service-hosted-in-SharePoint.aspx)